# Count number of user inputs

Tags: java, input, numbers, counting

I searched for my query but couldn't find anything of use. I'm just starting to learn Java and I made a basic guessing game program. My problem is that I need to count the number of guesses the user makes and I'm unsure how to do this. I would really appreciate any help you guys could give me. Here is my code so far:

```
double ran;
ran = Math.random();
int r = (int)(ran*100);

Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
int g = 0;

System.out.print("Please make a guess between 1 and 100: ");
g = in.nextInt();

while (g!=r){

  if (g<=0){
    System.out.print("Game over.");
    System.exit(0); 
  }

  else if (g>r){
    System.out.print("Too high. Please guess again: ");
    g = in.nextInt();
  }

  else if (g<r){
    System.out.print("Too low. Please guess again: ");
    g = in.nextInt();                               
  }
}

System.out.print("Correct!");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you would want to maintain a counter, i.e. a variable that will keep count of the number of guesses, and you will want to increment the count by **one** each time you ask the user to make a guess. So basically, you should be incrementing the counter each time you invoke `g = in.nextInt();`

So here is what your code should probably be doing...

```
double ran;
ran = Math.random();
int r = (int)(ran*100);
Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
int g = 0;
System.out.print("Please make a guess between 1 and 100: ");
int counter = 0;
g = in.nextInt();
counter++;
while (g!=r) {
    if (g<=0) {
        System.out.print("Game over.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if (g>r) {
        System.out.print("Too high. Please guess again: ");
        g = in.nextInt();
        counter++;
    }
    else if (g<r) {
        System.out.print("Too low. Please guess again: ");
        g = in.nextInt();
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.print("Correct!");
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add it to my code. Very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want a variable to keep track of your guess count. Declare it somewhere that will only get run once per game, a la

```
int guessCount = 0
```

And then, within your guess loop, increment `guessCount`.

```
guessCount++
```

Answer (score 2):

have a count variable and increment it inside the while on every iteration.

```
    int count=0;
     while(g!=r) {

        count++;
        //rest of your logic goes here
        }
```